# Sorting error when associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, wice-grid

I have a sorting problem with using the gem wice_grid. I have a table/grid for sent messages and it contains various columns. In the messages controller:

```
def index
  @messages_grid = initialize_grid( Message,
                                    per_page:        40,
                                    order:           'messages.created_at',
                                    order_direction: 'desc' )
end
```

The gem offers a sorting functionality and that works for most of the columns. However for the columns that involve an associated table (User), sorting (and filtering) fail. If I click to sort on these columns, I get an error, which refers to the line in the view page: `<%= grid(@messages_grid, show_filters: :when_filtered, html: {class: 'my-grid'}) do |g|`:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"
LINE 1: ...ECT  "messages".* FROM "messages"  ORDER BY "users
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages"  ORDER BY "users"."username" asc LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

The column of concern here is as follows in my view page:

```
g.column name: 'Sender', model: 'User', attribute: 'username', auto_reload: true, html: {id: 'grid-cells'} do |message|
  unless message.sender.nil?
    link_to(message.sender.username, user_path(message.sender))
  end
end
```

Does anyone understand why sorting when associated tables are involved is going wrong? I'm using wice_grid 3.5.0, Rails 4.2.3 and the console displays no javascript errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :include in :initialize_grid to include associated tables. http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com/joining_tables